# Existence of multivariable function whos limit exists agrees for all paths that are functions but fails otherwise.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Consider $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, y)$. We know the limit for this function exists if for all paths, $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, y) = L$. In addition, if we want to show that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, y)$ does not exist, we can take $y=g(x)$ and y=$m(x)$ s.t. $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, g(x)) = T$ and $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, m(x)) = S$ with $S \neq T$ to conclude that the limit does not exist.

My questions is if for all functions $y=g(x)$, the limit $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, g(x)) = L$ agrees and is equal to $L$, does that allow us to conclude that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (a, b)} f(x, y) = L$? I would imagine that it is not enough since some paths do not need to be functions, but I can't imagine a pathological counter example that could have its limit agree for every well defined function but fail otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Are you only allowing functions of $x$? If so, you can take the function that is $1$ everywhere except the positive $y$ axis, where it is $0$.

If you allow functions of either variable: then I think that for every sequence converging to $(a,b)$, you can find a convergent subsequence which is given by a function in either $x$ or $y$.